# Declaring a globally-visible array in CodeIgniter for routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, visibility, dry

*(Totally new to CodeIgniter and php, not new to programming)*

In CodeIgniter, **how or where can I declare an array that will be accessible in the router (CI_Router), in my custom controller and in the view loader (CI_Loader)?** I want to avoid hard-coding data in the router and specifying the same data more than once (in the router and in the controller and/or view).

(Explanation follows; perhaps there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do.)

I have a site where I publish my freeware apps. The site is all static, but maintaining plain html by hand is a nightmare, so I'm trying to use CodeIgniter to generate the pages dynamically. Apart from a few loose ends like 'welcome' or 'contact info', the bulk of the site consists of highly structured application sections. Each app has the same set of pages: about, download, screenshots, etc. These pages all have the same exact layout and only differ in contents.

My main concern is maintainability and the amount of work that required to add a new app (or a new page for all apps). I see no reason to use multiple controllers (or even multiple views), because the only difference is in data (application identifiers), not in behavior or page layout.

My problem is with routing. I could do something like

```
$route['app1'] = 'main/apps/app1';
$route['app2'] = 'main/apps/app2';
```

...or loop over an array of app identifiers, but that seems really bad. When I add an application, I should not have to modify the router, since it's just another identifier added to a list, that will be used to pick page contents from an appropriate file.

What I would like to do instead is (pseudocode):

```
foreach (app in list_of_apps) {
  foreach (app_page in list_of_pages) {
    route['app/app_page'] = 'main/index/app/app_page'
  }
}
```

This would take care of all requests for 'app1/download' or 'app2/screenshots', etc. So where can I declare the arrays $list_of_apps and $list_of_pages so that they are visible in the router, in the controller, and later in view as well?

Comment: I suppose I could resolve this in the controller instead, but that seems messy, and since the router exists, this is the task it's there for. Also, the example is a little simplified. Instead of two arrays, I'll probably need a single multi-dimensional hash that will hold a "map" of the site, where the identifiers for sections (apps) and pages (within each section) will map to names of files containing the actual data for display. At least this seems a reasonable way and could handle situations where a particular app does not have a 'screenshots" page or has a page that other apps don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a simple regular expressions solution:

```
// set this to whatever controller/method you want as the index for the app
$route['([^/])']      = 'main/apps/$1';

// this is a sample "subpage" handler
$route['([^/])/(.*)'] = 'main/index/$1/$2';
```

If all "apps" follow the same URL structure, it shouldn't be too hard to make this very modular.

Comment: I see, but that would route everything to the controller, including all invalid requests. I was hoping to route only valid requests (URI segments I recognize), and send 404 for everything else. Otherwise the controller still needs code to determine if the URI makes sense to it, so why even bother with the regex?

Comment: Are the "recognized segments" stored in a database?  I assume from your question that the segments don't map to a specific controller function, so how else would you know if the segment is valid without checking the database first?  Just trying to get a better handle on the requirements...